# Create a table using arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

Our profeesser assigned this project but Im at a loss of how to do it. Normally I would figure it out on my own but Ive got a massive English paper due on the same day and I have to finish that also this weekend. The program is due on 11/12/13 but can be turned in by 11/19/13 with a 20% penalty to grade.

### Write and test a C++ program to complete the following project:

Generate a table of numbers for use in a math problem.

Ask the user for three numbers:

- The first number represents how many values are to be in the table (1
  to 25).
- The second number represents the first value in the table. (-1000 to
  +1000)
- The third number represents the increment between successive values
  in the table. (1 to 20)

Iterate through the selected values, generating and saving the following derived values from each value in the iteration:

- Square
- Square Root (only if the value is positive or zero, display “N/A” for
  all other values)
- Cube
- Cube Root (only if the value is positive or zero, display “N/A” for
  all other values)
- Whether the number is even or odd
- Whether the number is prime or not (Prepare a user-defined function
  based on the logic in  Assignment 5).

Save the results of the calculations in a set of arrays, one array for each calculated value.

After all values are calculated and saved, display the values in a tabular form with one column for each calculated value and a row for each set of values (corresponding to the first value read from the user).

Note that for each negative value in the first column, display “N/A” in the columns for square root and cube root.

Display “Even” or “Odd” for each number’s even/odd status. Display “True” or “False” for the number’s prime-ness.

Repeat this process until the user enters a count of zero for the number of values in the table.

**Bonus:** Read a series of three-number sets from a data file named triples.txt and create a table of numbers corresponding to each three-number set. Save the resulting tables of numbers to a single text file named numbers.csv in comma-separated-value format.

### Heres' what i have so far:

```
// TABLEation.cpp : builds a table based on user input.
//


using namespace std;
double square, squareroot,cube,cuberoot;
int initialValue,display,increment;
string even,prime;
const int SIZE=25;
int Value[SIZE];

bool isEven( int integer )
{

  if ( integer % 2== 0 )
     return true;
  else
     return false;
}

bool isPrime(int testValue) {
    int divisor=0, remainder=0;

if (testValue<2) return false;
        for(divisor=2; divisor<=sqrt(testValue);divisor++){
            if((testValue % divisor)==0) return false;
            }
            return true;
        }


int _tmain()
{
    do{
        begining:
        cout<<"Enter how many values to show (1-25)."<<endl;
        cin>>display;
    if((display>0) && (display<=25)){
        cout<<"Enter an initial Value (-1000 to 1000)."<<endl;
        cin>>initialValue;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"ERRROR! INVALID INPUT!TRY AGAIN"<<endl;
        goto begining;
        }
    if ((initialValue>= -1000) && (initialValue<=1000)){
        cout<<"Enter a number to increment by (1-20)"<<endl;
        cin>>increment;
        }
    else{
        cout<<"ERRROR! INVALID INPUT!TRY AGAIN"<<endl;
        goto begining;
        }

    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

where should I go from here?

Comment: Ok, and so what was your question?

Comment: Are you having issues understanding the math of a *square, square root, cube or cube root*?  If so, ask your instructor.

Comment: so I call those six funtions and do what with them?

Answer (score 4):

Since there is no question above I am guessing you want someone to either give you the answer, or give you hints towards the right direction.  I am going to pretend you are after the latter.  The problem is fairly straightforward.

```
Generate a table of numbers for use in a math problem.

Ask the user for three numbers: 
The first number represents how many values are to be in the table (1 to 25).
he second number represents the first value in the table. (-1000 to +1000)
The third number represents the increment between successive values in the table. (1 to 20)
```

Since below we see that you are to ask these questions in a loop until the first answer is 0 you could build a function "bool get_input(int &num_values, int &start_num, int &increment)"  This function will return false if the user puts in a value that is not within the ranges and true otherwise.  Now call this function in a while loop where you exit if the num_values is 0.

```
Iterate through the selected values, generating and saving the following derived values from each value in the iteration:
```

This is a for loop where i = start_num and at each iteration you increase i+=increment

for each iteration of your for loop you should be calling the following six functions:

```
Square
```

int square(int i) which returns the square of the value.

```
Square Root (only if the value is positive or zero, display “N/A” for all other values)
```

bool extract_square_root(int i, float &square_root) which returns false if the value is negative, otherwise it puts the square root into the reference variable.

```
Cube
```

int cube(int i) which returns the cube of the value.

```
Cube Root (only if the value is positive or zero, display “N/A” for all other values)
```

bool extract_cube_root(int i, float &cube_root) -- as above

```
Whether the number is even or odd
```

bool even_or_odd(int i) which returns true if the value is even and false otherwise.

```
Whether the number is prime or not (Prepare a user-defined function based on the logic in Assignment 5)
```

bool prime(int i) which returns true if the value is prime. (use assignment 5).

```
Save the results of the calculations in a set of arrays, one array for each calculated value.
```

for each result store it in an array (square_root_array, cube_root_array, etc.)

```
After all values are calculated and saved, display the values in a tabular form with one column for each calculated value and a row for each set of values (corresponding to the first value read from the user).
```

call a function void display_values(float square_root_array[], ...) which iterates through each of your arrays and prints the values according to the rules listed below:

```
Note that for each negative value in the first column, display “N/A” in the columns for square root and cube root.

Display “Even” or “Odd” for each number’s even/odd status.

Display “True” or “False” for the number’s prime-ness.
```

The next part is already handled by our while loop.

```
Repeat this process until the user enters a count of zero for the number of values in the table.
```

I will leave the Bonus for you to figure out.

```
Bonus: Read a series of three-number sets from a data file named triples.txt and create a table of numbers corresponding to each three-number set. Save the resulting tables of numbers to a single text file named numbers.csv in comma-separated-value format.
```

Good luck, and get used to working all nighters if you plan on taking a lot of CS.  It's par for the course.

P.S. If you follow these directions and look up how to do each step where you are unsure, you could get this project off of your plate in a couple hours.